# Why this IF statement doesn't print inside a loop

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

Could you please help me out to understand why the If statement is not executing. Thank you for your time.

```cpp
    void allPerfects (int a, int b){

     int minVal = minN(a, b);
     int maxVal = maxN(a, b);
     int sum =0;
     vector<int> v;

     while (minVal < maxVal){
        v.push_back(minVal);
        minVal++;
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < v.size() ;i++){        
         for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            sum += v[j];
         }
         if (sum == v[i]){
            printInt(v[i], false); printStr(" is a perfect number!", true);
         }
     }
    }
```

Comment: well is sum ever == v[i]?

Comment: how do you know it never executes? What is `printInt` and `printStr` ?

Comment: Add more print statements to show you the values if v[i] and sum right before the if is run.  Or if using an IDE learn how to set a breakpoint there.

Comment: @DaveS when in doubt, more print calls it is xD

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I am not exactly sure, what your code does, but it doesn't seem to me that it calculates perfect numbers (i.e. numbers that are the sum of their proper divisors).

Comment: Could be lots of things, like does `minN` and `maxN` work as expected? Because if they both return the same value `v` will remain empty.

Comment: Why do you expect the `if` to get hit? Spell out for us why your expectations are as they are and how you know they're not what's actually happening.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't expressed myself enough.
I did check with a debugger, all pieces execute except the IF statement. maxV and minV do work as expected and the vector populates as intended.
printInt/ printStr, just take int/str values and put them inside a"cout" , true or false  is to include/ exclude an endl at the end. 
I imputed the number 3 and 30. 6 and 28 fall under the condition.  
Thank you for your time, will improve the information and quality of my future posts.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there aren't any bugs in your code you'll only get a print out for:

```
allPerfects(a, b);
```

if there are consecutive integers `a`, `a + 1`, ... , `a + n` that sum up to `a + n + 1 < b`.

This is only true for:

`1 + 2 == 3`

and

`0 + 1 + 2 == 3`

so `a` has to be `0` or `1` and `b` has to be greater than or equal to `4`.

Edit: But this will only happen if you reset your `sum`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < v.size() ;i++){
     sum = 0;  // This line is missing.       
     for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
        sum += v[j];
     }
     if (sum == v[i]){
        printInt(v[i], false); printStr(" is a perfect number!", true);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks!!
Despite imputing a range like that, I cant print anything. The other parts seem to be executing properly so I am somewhat confused on how to solve it.
Thanks for your time!